# Willmore minimizers for genus $\geq 2$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations, dg.differential-geometry

For an immersed closed surface $f: \Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ the Willmore functional is defined as
$$
\cal W(f) = \int _{\Sigma}  \frac{1}{4}  |\vec H|^2   d \mu_g,
$$
where $\vec H$ is the mean curvature vector in $\mathbb R^3$and $g$ is the induced metric.

If $\Sigma$ is closed we have the estimate
$$
\cal W(f) \geq 4 \pi
$$
with equality only for $f$ parametrizing a round sphere.

Recently, the Willmore conjecture was proved (the paper can be found on arxiv), which states that for closed surfaces $\Sigma$ of genus $g \geq 1$ this estimate can be improved:
$$
\cal W(f) \geq 2 \pi^2
$$
with equality only for the Cilfford torus.

Are there any conjectures about the minimizers in the case of genus $g \geq 2$? And what happens if we consider surfaces immersed in some $\mathbb R^n$ instead of $\mathbb R ^3$?

Comment: Can you give an explici citing of the archiv paper?  

Comment: It is the following paper by Marques and Neves:  arXiv:1202.6036

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, by a result of Bauer and Kuwert, there exists a smooth minimizer of the Willmore functional in the class of compact surfaces with fixed genus g, for any g. They have Willmore functional below $8\pi$ and by a result of Kuwert, Li and Schaetzle, the Willmore functional of the minimzers for genus $g$ tends to $8\pi$ when $g$ goes to infinity.
Not much more is known about higher genus surfaces, but there is a vague conjecture, that the minimzers are  the so called Lawson surface $\xi_{g,1}.$

Comment: The paper of Lawson where $\xi_{g,1}$ was introduced is here: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970625

Answer (score 3):

I remember there is a paper by Kusner named: comparison surfaces for the Willmore problem in which the author 
conjectured that the Lawson surface(see Sebastian's answer) minimizes the Willmore energy of genus g surface. For surfaces immersed in R^n, it is also conjectured the Clifford torus should be the minimizer, but it seems to me that this is still an open question.

Comment: Kusner's paper is here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102650153 .  There's also a paper of Hsu, Kusner and Sullivan looking at discrete approximations which give some kind of evidence towards this conjecture as well http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1048622023