# Integral of Square of Mean Curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Let us assume $\text{H}$ is the mean curvature of a compact surface in $\mathbb E^3$ and $g$ is its genus.

- When $g$ is arbitrary, we have $\int_{\mathbb S^2}\text{H}^2dV=4\pi$ and $\int_{\Sigma}\text{H}^2dV\geq4\pi$.
- When $g=1$, we have $\int_{\mathbb T^2}\text{H}^2dV\geq2\pi^{2}$ and $\int_{\Sigma}\text{H}^2dV\geq2\pi^{2}$.
- I want to ask that these theorems can be generalized to a compact surface with $g>1$ in $\mathbb E^3$? And the statement below is right or not?
  $$\text{When}~~g(\Sigma_{1})>g(\Sigma_{2})\text{, then do we have} \int_{\Sigma_{1}}\text{H}^2dV\geq\int_{\Sigma_{2}}\text{H}^2dV\text{?}$$

Comment: Look up the literature on the Willmore problem, and you will get the answers to your questions.  A good place to start is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willmore_conjecture, for example.

Comment: Google "Willmore functional", and check out this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92013/willmore-minimizers-for-genus-geq-2

Comment: As for (3), as far as I know, the first person to study this question was Leon Simon: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1243525, who proved certain existence results for minimizers. This paper is very beautiful and the techniques in here have been applied repeatedly to other problems.