# Monotonicity of infimum of the Willmore energy with prescribed genus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let 
$$
\beta_g:=\inf\{\frac14\int_\Sigma H^2 d\mu \hspace{0.2cm} | \hspace{0.2cm} \Sigma\subset \mathbb
R^{3}, \operatorname{genus}(\Sigma)=g \}
$$
be the infimum of the Willmore energy of embedded genus-$g$ surfaces. A standard result by Willmore says that $\beta_0=4\pi$ and Marquez-Neves showed that $\beta_1=2\pi^2$ as well as $\beta_g\geq 2\pi^2$ for $g\geq 1$. By estimating the Willmore energy of the Lawson surfaces, one finds $\beta_g<8\pi$ for all $g$. On the other hand, by a result of Kuwert-Li-Schaetzle, one has $\beta_g\to 8\pi$ as $g$ tends to infinity. This suggests that $\beta_g$ is (perhaps strictly) non-decreasing in $g$. I am wondering if this is true?

See also [Willmore minimizers for genus $\geq 2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92013/willmore-minimizers-for-genus-geq-2) for a related question.

Comment: As far as I know, nobody has been able to calculate  the Willmore energy for Lawson surfaces of genus bigger than 1, but it is only possible to estimate their energy.

Comment: You're completely right, I just edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the paper you reference, this question was posed on p. 446 of this paper

*Kühnel, Wolfgang; Pinkall, Ulrich*, [**On total mean curvatures**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/qmath/37.4.437), Q. J. Math., Oxf. II. Ser. 37, 437-447 (1986). [ZBL0627.53044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0627.53044).

I found 19 papers citing this paper on Google scholar. Of these, one is a [survey paper by Kuwert and Schätzle](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-88-7642-427-4_1.pdf) from 2012 which reproves the Kuwert-Li-Schäzle result (and doesn't mention the monotonicity question). A cursory look at the titles and abstracts indicates that this question doesn't seem to have been resolved (although there are several papers by Kuwert-Schäzle which address related questions). Presumably a paper proving monotonicity would cite their paper, so I'm guessing that this is still an open question since 1986.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the following does not answer your question, but in few of the Kusner conjecture that the Lawson surface $\xi_{g,1}$ should minimize the Willmore energy for closed surface of genus $g$, it still might be interesting: it can be proven that the Willmore energy $\mathcal W(g)$ of $\xi_{g,1}$ has the asymptotic behaviour $$\mathcal W(g)=8\pi\, (1-\frac{\ln{2}}{2g}+\frac{\ln{2}}{2g^2}+O(\frac{1}{g^3})\, ).$$ In particular, the Willmore energy of the Lawson surfaces $\xi_{g,1}$ is increasing for $g\geq N_0\in\mathbb N.$